# Android-studio problem with ContentResolver.query() when using regex for selection

Tags: android, android-studio, android-contentresolver

I am trying to query filtered audio files with the following line of code

```
musicResolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
musicUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
musicCursor = musicResolver.query(musicUri,null,"TITLE != 'AUD-.*-WA.*' ",null,null);
```

Eventhough i am using that regex in query i am getting audio files files with these titles.

AUD-201706-WA00002

AUD-201706-WA00035

AUD-201706-WA00042

I added ^ at the start of regex but it is also not working.

Comment: On Android Q  ??

Comment: No Lollipop or greater

Comment: Where did you read that MediaStore understands regex?

Comment: it is similar to sql query right

Comment: `Where did you read that MediaStore understands regex? `